# How to access OWIN Authentication Options from outside the Owin authentication flow

Tags: c#, owin

Inside of my OwinStartup.cs, I defined an Authentication provider and set its options:

```
var authOptions = new AuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientId = "myId",
    ClientSecret = "verysecret"
};

app.UseMyAwesoneAuthentication(authOptions);
```

How can I get to the `AuthenticationOptions` object of the Authentication provider from within an ASP.Net MVC controller? I can access the OWIN context inside of the controller:

```
var owinContext = Request.GetOwinContext();
```

but have not found a way to get to the provider's `AuthenticationOptions` object other than making it a static object.

Is this okay?

**EDIT: why am I doing this?**

`UseMyAwesomeAuthentication()` is an extension method of my custom authentication provider, it adds the provider to the Owin `IAppBuilder`. Besides standard OAuth2 authentication against a 3rd party, the provider also has an extension method to fetch additional data from the 3rd party API using an access token obtained during initial authentication.

To call the 3rd party API outside of the Owin authentication process, the extension method needs access to the ClientID, ClientSecret and endpoint url data stored in the options object.

I changed the title to make it clearer what my actual objective is.

Comment: Why do you want to read the authentication options? And what is `UseMyAwesomeAuthentication()`?.

Comment: @Progman Good question - I edited my question to make it clearer why I am doing this.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. It should show how/where you want to access the configuration data. It sounds like a huge security problem/risk when you have a 3rd party library which needs to access the authentication data of your custom authentication provide. Maybe it becomes more clear when you show what you already have and what you are trying to do. It kind sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: @Progman Thank you for pointing out the security aspect. Now I understand why it is not possible. I solved my problem by making the needed configuration data available to an extension method inside of the provider. I still needed to use some static variables but it is now all contained in the provider itself. The application' controller calls the extension method and is agnostic to the configuration data.